# Getting the 308 Permanent Redirect from GET http://xxxxxx/api/xx/xx

Tags: java

I am hitting a GET api using resttemplate (spring boot service) but I facing the issue like **Getting the 308 Permanent Redirect from GET http://xxxxxx/api/xx/xx**

If I hit the same api using postman & getting the proper response.
So I have tried to create the POJO based on the postman's response & getting **Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class NetworksResponse] and content type [text/html]**

If I change the response class as string then getting

```
<html>
<head><title>308 Permanent Redirect</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>308 Permanent Redirect</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried multiple solution by adding

```
`
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.TEXT_HTML));
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(converter);`
```

then I am getting **Error while extracting response for type [class java.lang.String] and content type [text/html]**

Not sure why this is happening if the response is in text/html then after adding the converter why it showing? **Error while extracting response for type [class java.lang.String] and content type [text/html]**

I am expecting Json response which can be mapped with the pojo that I have created.